# How do I get the length of a regex match in vim?

Tags: regex, vim

If I want to get the length of each match within the parentheses in the following regex, how do I do it?:

```
^\(\-\+\s\)\+
```

I'm trying to modify the width of columns in a buffer with data that is laid out as a table.  Since the first two rows of the table will look like this

```
 DESIGN_ID DESIGN_YEAR SOURCE_REFERENCE
---------- ----------- ----------------
```

I want to use the regular expression to find the current width of each column.

Comment: you can save on escapings with the \v switch ([very magic](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/\v)): `\v^(-+\s)+`  Escaping the `-` is not necessary in either case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, how do you want to capture it?

This will put it at the beginning of all the matching lines:

```
:%s/^-\+\%(\s-\+\)*\s\?$/\=strlen(submatch(0)) . ': '. submatch(0)
```

`\=` lets you substitute the result of a vimscript expression for a matching string.
`submatch(0)` is the string matched (`submatch(n)` would be the nth group).

Comment: with very magic: `:%s/\v^-+%(\s-+)*\s?$/\=strlen(submatch(0)) . ': '. submatch(0)`

Comment: instead of using + and \? here, I'd suggest using \{1,} and \{-}, because both gives you a bit more flexibility and makes it easier to change around. [pattern]\{n,m} means match where pattern between n and m times. [pattern]\{n,-} the '-' operator makes it non-greedy

Comment: The relevant help page for this can be found under `sub-replace-expression`.